# How do I extract a single attribute from an XML file?

Tags: sed, regex, xml

I'm not really familiar with regex, sed, etc. and a bit lazy to figure it out right this moment, so how do I extract this line:

```
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:50 am" sunset="7:06 pm"/>
```

Let me know if more of the xml structure is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the input data (your XML file) is structured, you're better off using a query on that structured data, rather than treating it as plain text and messing with regular expressions.

We can use `xmllint --xpath` to evaluate an XPath expression on your xml input:

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'string(rss/channel/*[local-name()="astronomy"]/@sunrise)' weather.xml
6:48 am
```

- this is a little convoluted, as we have to deal with the different namespaces in that file, but works nonetheless.

For more information about XPath, the specification is at http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Comment: separate issue, but after entering this command, the user@hostname does not begin on a new line, but displays on the same line as the output. I see this sometimes. Why does this happen? Also, thx ;)

Comment: This is because the output does not end with its own newline character. eg. `printf 'hello'` vs. `printf 'hello\n'`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use regex or sed. You use an XML parser and an XML query language (XPath or XQuery). And I'm afraid the details do depend on context: for example, "yweather" is a short name (prefix) for a namespace, and you need to know what namespace it represents.

Comment: example xml document here: http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=USwi0288&u=f

Comment: i've found xmlstarlet - using that, how would I extract the sunrise and sunset?

Comment: Adding to this: [Stackoverflow.com: html - RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4316166)

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer, as Michael Kay says, is to use an XML-specific tool.

For a quick and dirty solution, here is a sed approach.  Let's start with this file:

```
$ cat file
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:50 am" sunset="7:06 pm"/>
```

To extract sunset time:

```
$ sed -rn 's/.*sunset="([^"]*)".*/\1/p' file
7:06 pm
```

To understand the regex, let's break it into three parts:

1. `.*` matches from the beginning of the line up until the second part
2. This part, `sunset="([^"]*)"`, matches the characters `sunset="`, followed by any number of characters except `"`, followed by the closing `"`.  The expression `[^"]` means any character except `"` and `[^"]*` means any number of such characters. The parens, `(...)`, captures the characters inside the `"..."` into sed's group 1 which we later reference as `\1`.
3. `.*`  matches all the characters after the sunset expression.

Answer (score 0):

I will give same answer of [Jeremy Kerr](https://askubuntu.com/a/600481/632766) but giving it an `xml` in example.

We have an xml file called `config.xml` in out root folder, and we want to read a attribute or a property of a tag, let it be the `widget` tag.

`config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="16" id="co.app.world" ios-CFBundleVersion="0.1.3" version="3.0.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>AppName</name>
    <description>Description.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
</widget>
```

We want to get the `android-versionCode` property value, we type this in the terminal:

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//*[local-name()='widget']/@android-versionCode)" config.xml
```

Output:

```
16
```

Explanation: we use `/*[local-name()='widget']` to map the `widget` tag, and then `@android-versionCode` to read the property of this.